# Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: mysql

При попытке восстановить 50-гиговую базу данных из дампа примерно на 7–10% рвётся импорт с ошибкой Lost connection to MySQL server during query. Max_allowed_packet = 62G. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Таймаут маловат.

Comment: Как именно вы восстанавливаете базу?

Comment: @Akina, таймаут чего? connect_timeout и wait_timeout выставлены по 28800.

Comment: @InDevX, pv /path/file.sql | mysql dbname.

Comment: Попробуйте через source импортировать.. С месяц назад была похожая проблема, в итоге пришли к импорту через mysql shell. А, вообще, посмотрите логи

Comment: @InDevX, получилось, спасибо!